# .Net Soap WSDL webservice call from php not responding

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am getting issue to call brandbank webservice via php by using nusoap.php library.
 I have to fetch data from Brandbank webservice which they exposed at
 https://www.i-label.net/partners/webservices/datafeedbasic/extractdata.asmx?WSDL
I have made my code in php by using  nusoap.php library but getting errors

MY code

```
require_once "nusoap.php";
$client = new nusoap_client("https://www.i-label.net/partners/webservices/datafeedbasic/extractdata.asmx?WSDL");
$error = $client->getError();
if ($error) {
    echo "<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
}
$param = array('ExternalCallerId'=>' 32 char     key ','GTIN'=>'04015400440819','Description'=>'TAMPAX BLUE BOX MINI 20s','OwnLabel'=>'false','Category'=>'HHB','HasImage'=>'false');
$client->setUseCurl(true);
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
$result = $client->call("GetUnsentProductData", $param);

if ($client->fault) {
    echo "<h2>Fault</h2><pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
}
else {
    $error = $client->getError();
    if ($error) {
        echo "<h2>Error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
    }
else {
    echo "<h2>Products Info</h2><pre>";
    echo $result;
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

}

Here is response of webservice

```
Array
(
    [faultcode] => soap:Server
    [faultstring] => Server was unable to process request. ---> An exception has occured whilst processing your request. The details have been logged, and the system administrator has been notified
    [detail] => 
)
```

Brandbank WSDL link: https://www.i-label.net/partners/webservices/datafeedbasic/extractdata.asmx?WSDL
The problem that I am facing I don’t know how to send them product list in parameters along with this soap call.

Answer (score 0):

I can see this ticket is old, but it appears you are trying to send Coverage file information to the GetUnsent endpoint.

The endpoint for Coverage can be found via https://www.i-label.net/partners/webservices/datafeedbasic/extractdata.asmx?WSDL